# SQL Query - How to set the query results header as we want

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please look at the query below and its results.

**Query:**

```
Select T.TestTypeCode   
       T.Num1 As 'Friday - 09/14/2012'  
       T.Num2 As 'Saturday - 09/15/2012'    
       T.Num3 As 'Sunday 09/16/2012'    
       T.Num4 As 'Monday 09/17/2012'  
From Table T
```

**Results:**

```
TestTypeCode    Friday - 09/14/2012 Saturday - 09/15/2012   Sunday 09/16/2012   Monday 09/17/2012
    Open        60                  60                      60                  0
    Open        48                  48                      48                  0
    Open        28                  28                      28                  0
```

IF you see the above Query and Results, The column names '**Friday - 09/14/2012**','**Saturday - 09/15/2012**','**Sunday 09/16/2012**'And '**Monday 09/17/2012**' are mentioned manually,

But If the client execute the query on  '**Tuesday 09/18/2012**' Then He has to see the column names as '**Tuesday-09/18/2012**','**Wednesday-09/19/2012**','**Thursday-09/20/2012**' And '**Friday-9/21/2012**'

So, the column names should generate automatically for next four days, whenever the client runs the query.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Ignore my answer - It won't work as the column name. It must be a literal, I think, in that position.

Comment: can't you build a variable and input it as the `AS 'Friday - 09/14/2012`?

Comment: No, you can't build a variable as a column name. It must be known at compile time. - That's why I deleted my answer when I realised that it wouldn't work in this instance.

Comment: Malinone, I tried by assigning the string to variable and assigned to query, thats not worked, Select Num1 As 'It should be string' from table 1

Comment: @OverflowUser can you post sample data not from the result set?  Data from the tables as well as the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing needs to be done in the Front end and not in the SQL.

SSRS, Crystal Reports, or some other Reporting Software is where you would create the column names that you want.

I am assuming the Day of the week thing is for the Client and not for you, which means that this should be done in the Front End, on Reporting Software.

Clients shouldn't be executing SQL, they should be running reports.

Comment: I was curious to see the results from DB side. Any way thank You for your postings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like

```
SELECT T.TestTypeCode, T.Num1 AS DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()), ...
```

Comment: that just gives you the next day. in `DATETIME` Format which is '2012-09-15 ...` of the Date tomorrow  it gives the time and everything else